# JENKINS work-space is not rendering the project structure in Jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new Jenkins using Jenkins war ( 1.651.3) deployed on tomcat 6   running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server.
Jenkins configuration has 1 master and slave.

The issue what I am facing is that whenever I build a job on master  I could see the project Work-space  ( src and target folder) via UI, but If I build a project on slaves system  I can’t see project workspace content.

Is there any configuration I am missing?

[image: master view after build done]

[image: Slave View after build done]

Comment: Are you sure the workspace is not deleted? Can you verify it exists in the slave?

Comment: the workspace is not deleted the files are available in path ,  The path of work-space is - /opt/cloudhost/jenkinsHome/jobs/TestGiby/workspace/NumberGenerator
 same as Master .

Comment: Can you try to configure your slave again, this time try and change the  
  Remote root directory to some place like /tmp/jenkins-slave